# Cargar div dentro de otro

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un div por ejemplo este

```
<div class="div1">
   <h1>Titulo</h2>
   <p>texto</p>
</div>
```

entonces quiero saber si con js se div1 se puede cargar dentro de otro div osea algo asi

```
<div class="div2">ç
   <div class="div1">
      <h1>Titulo</h2>
      <p>texto</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que pides, tienes que mover los elementos de un item a otro. Para eso existe la función **[appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)** en `JQuery` que lo hace.

```js
  function generarDiv(){
    document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='segundoDiv'></div>"; 

    $("#divPadre").appendTo("#segundoDiv");
  }
```

```css
  #divPadre, #segundoDiv{
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="divPadre">
   <h3>Titulo</h3>
   <p>texto</p>
   <button type="button" onClick="generarDiv();">Generar Div</button>
</div>
```

---

*Ya como nota, una vez que ejecutes la función, la bloquería de alguna manera para no causar ningún error.*

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de [Black Hole](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258784/39913) es una opción. También se puede usar la opción de usar el atributo [`innerHTML`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).

Puedes declarar una variable que apunte hacia algún elemento en tu HTML usando `{nombre_elemento} = document.getElementById('{id}');.` y despues llamar `{nombre_elemento}.innerHTML='{Nuevo HTML}';`
Todo lo que se encuentra dentro sera cambiado por el valor que se le asigno a su atributo `innerHTML`.

#### Ejemplo

```js
divParent = document.getElementById('div2');
divParent.innerHTML = '<div id="div1"><h1>Titulo</h1><p>Texto</p></div>';
```

```html
<div id="div2">
  <h1>Titulo</h1>
  <p>Texto</p>
</div>
```

Esta opción podría parecer mas corta pero el código tal vez sea un poco mas difícil de leer.

Comment: Asi es, esta es como la manera directa de llevarse acabo, mientras que yo mostre como manipular objectos del DOM, es bueno mostrar todas las opciones

Answer (score 0):

pues tienes que jugar con los elementos del DOM, crearlos y añadirlos a otros dom elementos, aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona:

```js
var padre = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");

var div = document.createElement("div");//creamos el div

//creamos el titulo
var h1 = document.createElement("h1");
var h1Text = document.createTextNode("TituloAgregado");
h1.appendChild(h1Text);

//creamos el parrafo
var p = document.createElement("p");
var pText = document.createTextNode("textoAgregado");
p.appendChild(pText);

//agregamos el titulo y el parrafo al div creado
div.appendChild(h1);
div.appendChild(p);

//añadimos todo al div seleccionado, en este caso el primer div que contenga la clase _div2_
padre[0].appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div class="div2">
   <div class="div1">
      <h1>Titulo</h2>
      <p>texto</p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear primero tu segundo div y agregarlo en el body de tu documento, y despues tomar ese div2 e insertarle tu div1, algo así:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1");
document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='div2'></div>"
document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[0].appendChild(div1[0]);
```

```html
<body>
<div class="div1">
   <h1>Titulo</h1>
   <p>texto</p>
</div>
</body>
```